# secondary jekyll markdown parser as a plugin?

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll

I'm trying to implement a custom markdown processor for a collection in jekyll.  The idea is based on [this](https://www.illogicalexpressions.com/development/2016/11/13/markdown-it.html). Unfortunately, due to the bug described [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6211) such functionality is broken due to a core jekyll bug in the renderer.  The gist of the bug is that passing collection files into a non-core renderer returns a null string, so the post text disappears.

Is it possible to call a secondary markdown renderer as a plugin in jekyll?

The idea being, I could pipe the output of {{ collection.content | to-my-plugin }} rather than replacing the _config markdown parser, which seems to trigger the bug.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I actually disagree with the blog post you've linked, as the supported kramdown parser has the [footnote capability](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#footnotes) he hacked jekyll to achieve.

Comment: I agree with @MarkThomas. That bug report is about template tags. The Markdown parser does not even handle the template tags. They are handled separately before the text is passed to the Markdown parser. Changing Markdown parsers will have no effect on that issue.

Comment: Because of the linked bug.  That bug effectively limits me to only using bundled parsers.  External parsers (I suspect) change the order in which the build processes execute, resulting in null strings for (collection) post text.  I'm looking to add markdown extensions that are not supported in any of the bundled parsers, which is relatively simple with a javascript based parser run via node, but not so simple with the bundled parsers.